# Overlapping HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I have a web page with some `<a>` elements. When the browser is enlarged the elements is next to each other as i want it, but when i re-size the browser smaller the elements start to overlap each other. What am i supposed to do? I tried position:fixed, absolute and relative in the style tags but no satisfying result. If the browser gets re-sized smaller i want to be able to to scroll to the parts that could not fit in. Here is my code in one html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body{
margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#home{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    margin:  0px 10px 0px 200px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background: linear-gradient(white, orange);
}

#proj{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background: linear-gradient(white, orange);
}

#for{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background: linear-gradient(white, orange);
}

#about{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background: linear-gradient(white, orange);
}

</style>
<div id="heading">
<a href="#" id="home"><font face="arial">HOME</font></a>
<a href="#" id="proj"><font face="arial">PROJECTS</font></a>
<a href="#" id="for"><font face="arial">FORUM</font></a>
<a href="#" id="about"><font face="arial">ABOUT</font></a>
</div>
</head>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why are your elements in the `<head>` and not the `<body>`? Also, why are you defining separate CSS based on each id when the actual settings are the same for each element? Use a common class. (Having said that, `display:inline-block` for your anchors seems to fix most of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/WWL73/)

Comment: One possible solution: try specifying the width of the wrapping div, that is, add something like this CSS: `#heading{ min-width: 950px; }`. It may be just what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is simplified version of your code with solution...

**HTML Part**

```
<div id="heading">
<font face="arial">
    <a href="#" class="cls" id="home">HOME</a>
    <a href="#" class="cls" id="proj">PROJECTS</a>
    <a href="#" class="cls" id="for">FORUM</a>
    <a href="#" class="cls" id="about">ABOUT</a>
</font>
</div>
```

**CSS Part**

```
.cls{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    padding: 10px ;
    width:20px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background: linear-gradient(white, orange);

    //add this to solve your problem...
    line-height:3em;
    position:relative;
}
```

Fiddle: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilButani/Gm2xu/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Media Queries to adjust your CSS at different breakpoints. Here's a basic intro to it: http://www.vanseodesign.com/web-design/media-query-breakpoints/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { // different CSS for screens smallers than 769px.
    #heading {    padding-left: 0;    }
    #heading a { margin:5px; width: 130px; }
}
```

I put together a fiddle to show you how and to show you other ways to do this, including getting rid of the font tags. http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/C4AGF/

Answer (score 0):

Using `line-height` to avoid overlapping:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body{
margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background: linear-gradient(white, orange);   
    line-height: 50px; 
}
#home{
    margin:  0px 10px 0px 200px;
}

#proj{ 
    margin: 10px;
}

#for{ 
    margin: 10px;
}
#about{ 
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<div id="heading">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="home"><font face="arial">HOME</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="proj"><font face="arial">PROJECTS</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="for"><font face="arial">FORUM</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="about"><font face="arial">ABOUT</font></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</head>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is simplified version of your code with solution...

**css code**

```
#home {
    background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #FFA500) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 50px;
   /* margin: 0 10px 0 200px;*/ //Remove Margin
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 20px; }

//add css to display button in the center of the page
#heading{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 720px; 
}
```